# Does SWRL Protege Drools engine infer knowledge from owl:equivalentClass?

Tags: ontology, protege, swrl

I am trying to build some SWRL rules with `swrlx:makeOwlThing` thus using drools in protege.

However, one of my rules depends on individuals whose class is inferred from assertion of `owl:equivalentClass`. If I run Pellet for example the equivalent class assertion works.

However when I click OWL+SWRL , and  Run drools, my rule does not work since the `owl:equivalentClass` was never asserted. Hence I did an experiment and manually made another SWRL rule that replicates the  `owl:equivalentClass` assertion I made on the protege editor.

Attached is the ontology where I am testing this. Rule S1 is the rule I manually had to add to replicate the two `owl:equivalentClass` assertions in

```
###  http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2023/11/untitled-ontology-330#ProcessData
:ProcessData rdf:type owl:Class ;
             owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                   owl:onProperty :isProcessData ;
                                   owl:hasValue "true"^^xsd:boolean
                                 ] .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2023/11/untitled-ontology-330#ProcessDataInput
:ProcessDataInput rdf:type owl:Class ;
                  owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                        owl:onProperty :hasAE ;
                                        owl:hasValue :Vel
                                      ] ;
                  rdfs:subClassOf :ProcessData .
```

So I am not sure if something is missing on my side or should I just copy all my `owl:equivalentClass` as SWRL rules ?

Full ontology in turtle format

https://github.com/vChavezB/swrl_equivalent_stack_ovflow/blob/main/test.ttl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not missing anything here and the behaviour you witnessed it expected.

You have 2 options:

1. Run both an OWL2 reasoner like Pellet and the Drools engine. The reasoner will infer equivalence relations and other inferences and based on those inferences Drools can infer further inferences.
2. Add additional rules to your SWRL rules to replicate inferences from the OWL reasoner to be able to only run the Drools engine.

My suggestion will be to give preference to option 1. My motivation is as follows.

**TL;DR**: Strictly speaking the algorithms for making inferences using an OWL2 reasoner versus using a rules engine are different algorithms. There is some overlap between inferences made using and OWL2 reasoner and a rules engine. But the is also inferences that an OWL2 reasoner can make that a rules engine cannot make, and the are inferences that rule engine can make that an OWL2 reasoner cannot make. Hence, using them together gives you the best of both worlds.

**Longer explanation**

An OWL2 reasoner can give you way more inferences than what can be derived from a rules engine. The inferences from an OWL2 reasoner depends on the expressivity of your ontology - the more expressive your ontology, the more inferences can be made. Conversely, if your ontology is not very expressive, only a few inferences can be made. For an expressive ontology, you will need to add lots of rules to replicate this. Moreover, some inferences cannot be made using a rules engine. However, if your ontology is not very expressive, it may be possible replicate the axioms of your ontology as rules.

Why then use a rules engine? The inferences gained from a rules engine is not as rich as that from an ontology, but there are some inferences that cannot be made from a OWL2 reasoner. The main advantage of a rules engine is when dealing with lots of individuals (like in the case of an RDF triple store), its performance is orders of magnitude better than that of an OWL2 reasoner.

My suggestion for giving preference for option 1 is that you are using Protege, so it is rather unlikely that you are dealing with lots of individuals.

Comment: My use case involves a Software (SW) that will generate individuals automatically and use the owl assertions + swrl rules for inference. I need SWRL since I have expressions that cannot be represented only with OWL. Protege at the moment is just used for defining the ontology but everything will be integrated in another SW. I do not know about best practices so based on your insightful answer I might replicate the owl equivalences as the SWRL rules depend on them to work.

Comment: The ontology will be used in a SW that talks only with the API versions (owl-api, pellet, drools). But right now since I am just verifying that my proof-of-concept works I am not using the APIs due to time constraints for my research.

Comment: So if I want to go with option #1, do you know how can I make drools engine (i.e., SWRL Tab in Protege) import the inferences from pellet ? Because thats what I thought I could do but doesnt happen.

Comment: Once reasoning has completed in Protege, you can do a "File->Export inferred axioms as ontology ...". Make sure also to select "Include asserted axioms". Then you can use the resulting .owl as your ontology.

Comment: that worked!  My takeway is to keep the owl equivalence assertions as they are more expressive and self documenting for the ontolgoy than swrl. For protege you can either:
1. Infer the equivalences from a reasoner (e.g., pellet) and export the assertions and then use swrl with drools.
2. For a faster debugging just copy the equivalnces as SWRL, if you dont have too many.